# jQuery plugin scope issue of private function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I seem to be experiencing a scope issue with my internal function 'getFontSize'. I am able to select DOM elements from within the plugin but not from within the 'getFontSize' function

```
    (function ($) {
        $.fn.pluginName = function(options) {
            options = $.extend({}, $.fn.pluginName.defaults, options);

            return this.each(function() {
                // do stuff

            });
        } 

        // Default options
        $.fn.pluginName.defaults = {

            fontSize: getFontSize('body', '16px')
        }; // defaults close

        // get font-size
        function getFontSize(selector, dSize) {
            var fSize = $(selector).css('font-size') || dSize;
            fSize = (fSize.indexOf('px') >= 0) ? fSize : dSize;
            var factor = (fSize.indexOf('em') >= 0) ? fSize : '1';
            factor = (fSize.indexOf('%') >= 0) ? String(Number(fSize.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "")) / 100) : '1';
            return Number(fSize.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "") * Number(factor.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "")));
        };

    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: I belive you dont need to use `$(selector)` since you are already inside the jquery function, you should be able to just use `this` or `$(this)` , I havent written a jquery plugin since jquery was new so this may have changed. another issue could be closures could try `(function getFontSize(...) { })($);`

Comment: `console.log($)`. It might be `undefined` if jQuery hasn't loaded. if that's the case, you need the whole initiation to run on `$(document).ready`

Comment: @Mouseroot - I am using the getFontSize function to get the existing font-size defined in the css of the body element. This is different from the the element the plugin is actually applied to so 'this' will not work

Comment: @TastySpaceApple - Thanks for your suggestion. I can confirm jQuery has loaded

Comment: On further testing it does in fact seem to be an issue with loading not scope. If I move the call to the plugin to the bottom of the HTML page then i am able to select DOM elements from within the getFontSize function. Any suggestions on how to ensure the defaults function does not execute until the DOM is ready (without resorting to calling it from the foot of the page)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for suggestions. I was able to get it to work in two different ways:

1. Turn the 'defaults' object into a function as per the following code:

   ```
   (function ($) {
       $.fn.pluginName = function(options) {
           options = $.extend({}, $.fn.pluginName.defaults(), options);

           return this.each(function() {
               // do stuff

           });
       } 

       // Default options
       $.fn.pluginName.defaults = function (){
           var optns = {
               fontSize: getFontSize('body', '16px')
           }
           return optns;
       };

       // get font-size
       function getFontSize(selector, dSize) {
           var fSize = $(selector).css('font-size') || dSize;
           fSize = (fSize.indexOf('px') >= 0) ? fSize : dSize;
           var factor = (fSize.indexOf('em') >= 0) ? fSize : '1';
           factor = (fSize.indexOf('%') >= 0) ? String(Number(fSize.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "")) / 100) : '1';
           return Number(fSize.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "") * Number(factor.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "")));
       };

   })(jQuery);
   ```
2. Option 2 is to move the 'default' object inside the plugin function as per the following tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/291290/How-To-Write-Plugin-in-jQuery

The second option seems more widely prescribed so I have used it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is the placement of the function within the anonymous jquery plugin function I think, according to the jquery plugin creation page

http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/ it should be

`$.fn.getFontSize = function(selector,dSize) { ... }` instead of having an external function that is outside the `$.fn` namespace,

however I havent tested it.

Comment: Thanks. I was not able to get this to work. I believe this is because the real issue has to do with when the getFontSize function is called. When 'defaults' is an object the getFontSize function is called as soon as the script is initialized - before the DOM is ready. As a function 'defaults' will wait until it is called by the plugin function - after the DOM is ready. See my suggested solutions above.